# add missing digit to split time and change the nan to 00.00

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

im using the fallowing code to calculate the total minutes in this 2 fields but i keep getting 0.00 instead of 00.00

```js
function calculate() {
             time1 = $("#field1").val().split(':'),
             time2 = $("#field2").val().split(':');
             hours1 = parseInt(time1[0], 10), 
             hours2 = parseInt(time2[0], 10),
             mins1 = parseInt(time1[1], 10),
             mins2 = parseInt(time2[1], 10);
             hours = hours2 - hours1,
             mins = 0;
         if(hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
         if(mins2 >= mins1) {
             mins = mins2 - mins1;
         } else {
             mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
         }
     
         // the result
         $("#total").val(hours + ':' + mins);         
     }
```

also i want to replace the nan to 00.00

Comment: Java is not the same language as JavaScript. Please do not use the tags interchangeably.

Comment: Where are coming all this variables? please put the complete Code

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `NaN` hours and minutes back to integers with:

```
if (!hours) {
  hours = 0;
}
if (!mins) {
  mins = 0;
}
```

Then simply prepend a `0` if the values are less than `10` (and greater than `0`):

```
if (hours < 10 && hours > 0) {
  hours = '0' + hours;
}
if (mins < 10 && mins > 0) {
  mins = '0' + mins;
}
```

This can be seen working in the following:

```js
function calculate() {
  time1 = $("#field1").val().split(':'),
  time2 = $("#field2").val().split(':');
  hours1 = parseInt(time1[0], 10),
  hours2 = parseInt(time2[0], 10),
  mins1 = parseInt(time1[1], 10),
  mins2 = parseInt(time2[1], 10);
  hours = hours2 - hours1,
  mins = 0;
  
  if (hours < 0) hours = 24 + hours;
  if (mins2 >= mins1) {
    mins = mins2 - mins1;
  } else {
    mins = (mins2 + 60) - mins1;
  }
  
  if (!hours) {
    hours = 0;
  }
  if (!mins) {
    mins = 0;
  }
  
  if (hours < 10 && hours > 0) {
    hours = '0' + hours;
  }
  if (mins < 10 && mins > 0) {
    mins = '0' + mins;
  }

  // the result
  $("#total").val(hours + ':' + mins);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="field1">
<input id="field2">
<button onclick="calculate()">Go</button>
<br /><br />
<input id="total">
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check if they are smaller than 10 like in this example:

```
   hours=(hours<10)?'0'+hours:hours;
   mins =(mins <10)?'0'+mins:mins;
```